# .htaccess mod_rewrite URL language

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to write a rule, that would redirect URL like this:

```
myweb.com/en/page
```

to

```
myweb.com/page.php?lang=en
```

This code:

```
RewriteRule ^/(cz|en)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L]
```

does not work (error 404). Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following:

```
RewriteRule ^/(cz|en)/(.*)$  $2.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to match the leading slash in RewriteRule's pattern on htaccess context :

```
RewriteRule ^(cz|en)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L]
```